# is there a way to create an app for floating window like samsung phone

Tags: android

i am creating an app which will recreate Samsung floating window capability for non Samsung smartphone,

well i found a thread suggesting this can be possible [App inside an app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23869037/app-inside-an-app)
some one commented to launch the app using intent and get x y placement using inject tools
and hence i tried launching app's Main-activity to run in fragment using intent well this sounds stupid and ya it doesn't work don't laugh,

```
Instrumentation m_Instrumentation = new Instrumentation();
m_Instrumentation.sendPointerSync(motionEvent);
```

i really want a way to open installed app to open in a fragment or activity that is  anything resizable.

Comment: Good question, but no need for the self-deprecating remarks "well this sounds stupid and ya it doesn't work don't laugh". Don't worry, no one is going to laugh; all you need do is ask the question simply and clearly, which you have done.

Answer (score 0):

I think that recreating Samsung floating window would be impossible with vanilla android.

You could try getting [Picture-In-Picture](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/picture-in-picture) to do what you want or maybe [Multi Window](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/multi-window) will fit your use case.