# Is there any possibility to install multiple app at once in android?

Tags: android, android-studio

And second is can we open install prompt(play store app) within an app ??
I want to install multiple application at one click in background please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm pretty sure you can't really install multiple applications in one click.

You can download multiple APK files outside of the app store at once, but in doing so, the system will prompt the user if they want the app to be installed, and that it was from an outside source.

You can have the app open the google play store app and take you to an installation page where the user can install the applications individually. If that is what you're looking for, check out this example:
[How to open the Google Play Store directly from my Android application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11753000/how-to-open-the-google-play-store-directly-from-my-android-application)

Comment: Is there any way to use multiple App within App ?

Comment: There is no way to specifically open another app inside your app with an unrooted device: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23869037/app-inside-an-app
You can open another app using your app though: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2780102/open-another-application-from-your-own-intent#7596063