# How to use a fragment from one application in another?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I'm part of a team developing several android applications for a combined system. The system contains administration tools, games and other kind of applications.

The users has requested that they from one application can access the settings of all apps in the system.

My initial idea was that each application could implement a settings fragment following a predefined interface which i then could load to show in my settings application.
I found this post, with a fairly new answer [Use external application fragment/activity inside application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7726702/use-external-application-fragment-activity-inside-application), and this is how I thought this could be implemented.

I tried implementing the example given by @sandrstar by it gives me the following error

```
04-24 07:02:36.596    1715-1715/? E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.IllegalAccessError: Class ref in pre-verified class resolved to unexpected implementation
        at dalvik.system.DexFile.defineClass(Native Method)
        at dalvik.system.DexFile.loadClassBinaryName(DexFile.java:211)
        at dalvik.system.DexPathList.findClass(DexPathList.java:315)
        at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:62)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
        at dk.giraf.launcher.test.mainapplication.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:46)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5039)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Is what I am attemping even possible? Other suggestions for implementations are welcome.

Comment: You could export all configuration into another APK and write providers so you can read those settings from any of your apps. http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-providers.html

Comment: Having read little about Content Providers, I'm not quite sure that they are the solution I'm looking for. To make it more clear, what I want is that each team (working on a specific app) can define their own UI and code to control the settings of their app, which can be used from their app, but also from the central settings app. The settings app will be much like the way iOS handles settings, but with the difference that a particular setting can be controlled from two places.

Comment: Some PackageManager sourcery combined with this http://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/filters.html could be what you neeed. I will elaborate further on an answer should you need more guidance