# How to load external fragment and resource in Android app

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-resources

I have a container app with several tabs, and I want to load fragment from another "plugin" app (another apk) to these tabs.

I found this [Use external application fragment/activity inside application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7726702), and I successfully loaded my fragment to my container app, but the problem is, it uses local resources to inflate the view, i.e. the resources of the container app (the "main" app), instead of the app that actually implement the fragment (the "plugin" app).

How can I let it uses the resources from the "plugin" app to inflate my view?

Comment: this is the same how you load the resources in your "normal" application

Comment: Ohhh my, are you using sandrstar's code from that link? You are entering a world of pain here! You are loading and executing a piece of code from another app, but _just the code_. As resources are just integer ids, when the external code loads a resource of course it references resources inside your own APK.

Comment: Yes, so when I want to use some string resource, it reference to another resource. Is there a better way to implement a plugin? (with UI/resources?)