# Can we load fragment from external installed app?

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment

I am developing an application where architecture is supposed to be "Plugin Architecture". So that we can add/edit some feature as plugin without working in main app.

Right now, I am able to transfer data from main app to other app(My Plugin app installed) and vice-versa using AIDL.

But i want to load Fragment from plugin app.
Is it possible and if is it then how?

I did lot of googling but only able to get this link. But problem is that How can we implement interface from other app?
[Use external application fragment/activity inside application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7726702/use-external-application-fragment-activity-inside-application)

Kindly, Help me to load fragment from other application or Go through above link and please help me to "How to implement interface from other app"?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Here's the most important reasons you should **NOT** do that:

1. If the user uninstalled the app you're using code from (let's call it the main app) your app (the host app) is likely to misfunction.
2. If the imported feature is updated in the main app, you'll probably want to update the host app as well.
3. If the user chooses to update only one of the two applications, this will cause problems in the host app
4. It will be much harder to maintain.

Here is **what you should do**, separate the features you want to share into libraries/sub-modules and use them in both the main and host applications. This will give you more control over the feature version in each app, and the user would not be required to install both applications in order to run the desired feature. refer to [this post](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidLibraryProjects/article.html) for more information how to do that.

Comment: Bro I got your point. but m working on Enterprise application which will not go to playstore. its a product which will runs on only big screen like TV Size.
So, if you have any idea to load fragment from other application. Please guide me.