# Can I use ClassLoader to load a fragment but also with the permissions from the APK?

Tags: android, android-fragments, classloader

I have one app and I want do dynamically load a fragment from a second app (that I will develop) the idea behind is that, Google play does not allow some permissions like Default Call app if the App is not a "call app", so my idea is to create a new APK and then the user will have to download from my website or somewhere else the apk, the main App will not have this logic of downloading apks (because this might be flagged as a malware), and then the idea is to load the Fragment using Classloader (which I manage to do it), or use a library like:
https://github.com/Catherine22/ClassLoader
The problem is lets say I have No internet permission in the first APK, and I have internet permission in the second APK, if I load the "second apk" Fragment in the Main app, I will receive an error because in the Main app I don't have internet permission.

While I understand that this looks like a good security measure, I just want to know if there is some possibilities to give to my users more features and options, Tasker do something similar to control WIFI using an old version companion, it might not be the same as I want but that gave me the idea to give to my users more features if they want it.
is this possible?
I used this snipped code from SO
[Use external application fragment/activity inside application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7726702/use-external-application-fragment-activity-inside-application)

```kotlin
var requiredClass: Class<*>? = null
            val apkPath = packageManager.getApplicationInfo("com.test.composetest", 0).sourceDir
            val dexTemp: File = getDir("temp_folder", 0)
            val fullName = "com.test.composetest.TestFragment"

            var isLoaded = true;

            // Check if class loaded
            try {
                requiredClass = Class.forName(fullName);
            } catch (e: ClassNotFoundException) {
                isLoaded = false;
            }

            if (!isLoaded) {
                val classLoader = DexClassLoader(
                    apkPath, dexTemp.absolutePath, null,
                    applicationContext.classLoader
                )

                requiredClass = classLoader.loadClass(fullName);
            }

            if (requiredClass != null) {
                // Try to cast to required interface to ensure that it's can be cast
                val holder = FragmentHolder::class.cast(requiredClass.newInstance())

                if (null != holder) {
                    val fragment: Fragment = holder.getFragment();

                    if (null != fragment) {
                        val trans: FragmentTransaction =
                            supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()

                        trans.add(R.id.fragmentPlace, fragment, "MyFragment").commit();
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (e: PackageManager.NameNotFoundException) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (e: ClassNotFoundException) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (e: InstantiationException) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (e: IllegalAccessException) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: Using `ClassLoader` like this might violate the developer distribution terms for the Play Store, FWIW. "The problem is lets say I have No internet permission in the first APK, and I have internet permission in the second APK, if I load the "second apk" Fragment in the Main app, I will receive an error because in the Main app I don't have internet permission." -- correct. Instead of doing this `ClassLoader` stuff, have the second APK actually do the work. Android has many forms of IPC: starting activities, starting or binding to services, etc.

Comment: thanks a lot @CommonsWare it makes sense,thanks for the help